# UIScrollview as main view IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiscrollview, scrollview

i'm trying to make a uiscrollview as main view in IOS 8 but i can't.

I have the following structure:

- View

  - Header_View (Like TabBar)
  - UIScrollView

    - ContentView

      - UIImage
      - UILabel_Text
      - UIButton

Sometimes the text is bigger than others so i don't know the exactly height of the view. With this structure when i try to scroll vertical nothing happens.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: are the content view dimensions larger than the scroll view dimensions?

Comment: use UITableView instead

Comment: looks like you have not applied proper constraints to your scrollview.

Comment: did you set contentSize of scrollview?

Comment: I tryed to use UITableView and happened 2 errors.
1. When i scroll, it is over the header view
2. the height is the devices height, so i can't see all the text.

Comment: I solve the first error but when i scroll down it returns to top.

Answer (score 0):

First take a int variable like ajustHeight in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : ViewController{
  int ajustHeight;
}
```

then in ViewController.m use this variable to get UILabel_Text height like below.

```
    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *successlabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 215, 75)];
    successlabel.text = message;
    successlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    successlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [successlabel sizeToFit]; 

    [expandableview addSubview:successlabel];

    ajustHeight   =  successlabel.frame.size.height;

}
```

Now you get successlabel height after that you can adjust the view and scrollview content height as well. if you create UILable in for loop then user like ajustHeight   +=  successlabel.frame.size.height;

Comment: I tried and the scroll is over the header view. How can the scroll hide below the header view?

Comment: ok then you can use this code " headerView.layer.zPosition = 1.0f; "